# How to do chain targeting on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qoun3gLb/). Why am I not able to target the id of Next and Previous `section` of selected a anchor link?

To get the next I tried all:

```
 var target = $(this).next('section').attr('id');
 var target = $(this).parent().parent().next('section').attr('id');
 var target = $(this).parent().next('section').attr('id');
 var target = $(this).parent().find('section').attr('id');
```

but was not able to grab the id of Next Section to the selected `.next-slide`

```
$(function(){
  $(".next-slide").on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).next('section').attr('id');
      target = "#"+target;
       console.log(target); 
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.next()` targets the next adjacent element, and there is no `section` that is next to `.next-slide` links on your page. To target the next `section` relative to the link you're clicking on, you need to find the parent `section` of the link, then target the next `section` via `$.next()`

You can find the parent `section` of the link by using `$.closest()`, which returns the first ancestor that matches your selector, then use `$.next('section')` to target the `section` that comes after that.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".next-slide").on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).closest('section').next('section').attr('id');
      target = "#"+target;
       console.log(target); 
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section1">
<div class="col-md-12 box" id="box-1">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/f3f5f6/f3f5f6' />
    </div>
    <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 up-pointer">
  </div>    
  <div class="col-md-12 down-pointer">
    <a role="button" class="pointer next-slide">
     <img src="http://www.caapc.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/map-marker-2-xxl.png" class="img-responsive" width="40px" height="40px" />
      </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<section id="section2">
<div class="col-md-12 box" id="box-1">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/f3f5f6/f3f5f6' />
    </div>
    <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 up-pointer">
  </div>    
  <div class="col-md-12 down-pointer">
    <a role="button" class="pointer next-slide">
     <img src="http://www.caapc.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/map-marker-2-xxl.png" class="img-responsive" width="40px" height="40px" />
      </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<section id="section3">
<div class="col-md-12 box" id="box-1">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/f3f5f6/f3f5f6' />
    </div>
    <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 up-pointer">
  </div>    
  <div class="col-md-12 down-pointer">
    <a role="button" class="pointer next-slide">
     <img src="http://www.caapc.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/map-marker-2-xxl.png" class="img-responsive" width="40px" height="40px" />
      </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<section id="section4">
<div class="col-md-12 box" id="box-1">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/f3f5f6/f3f5f6' />
    </div>
    <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 up-pointer">
  </div>    
  <div class="col-md-12 down-pointer">
    <a role="button" class="pointer next-slide">
     <img src="http://www.caapc.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/map-marker-2-xxl.png" class="img-responsive" width="40px" height="40px" />
      </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're missing in period in `next('.section')`. If you want to select the adjacent sibling with the class "section", use `.next('.section')`.</strike>

Okay, working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/qoun3gLb/1/)!

```
$(function(){
  $(".next-slide").on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).parents('section').next('section').attr('id');
      target = "#"+target;
       console.log(target); 
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Chris but section is not an class! it is a HTML stand alone tag, am I right?

Comment: @ChrisHappy you should really be including an explanation with your code instead of just the same. It's also recommended not to just cross out comments, etc. but instead of just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var target = $(this).parent().closest('section').attr('id');
```

> Closest() : For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Use closest to get the section that you need. Try this out.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75ssr9dk/)

[Closest Doc](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)